# GitHub Actions - You have an error in you YAML syntax

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have the following YAML specs for my action:

```
name: Build and test

on: [push, pull_request]

env:
  buildDir: ${{ github.workspace }}/build/

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, windows-2019, macos-10.15]
        include:
          - os: ubuntu-18.04
            triplet: x64-linux
          - os: ubuntu-20.04
            triplet: x64-linux
          - os: windows-2019
            triplet: x64-windows
          - os: macos-10.15
            triplet: x64-osx

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

I verified that this passes validation of https://yamlvalidator.com/. And yet GitHub is telling me there was an error in my YAML syntax at line 27 (last line). I tried various different indentations of that part but all yield the same result.
Furthermore I tried removing the matrix block above and also using 4 instead of 2 spaces to indent everything but these changes also were unable to resolve the error.

I have absolutely no clue what is going on here. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions jobs doesn't have a top-level steps key with an array value - steps is being interpreted as a job ID, but a job is an object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I could have sworn that I tested that before. But it seems like that version then had another flaw. I just tried again indenting the entire `steps` block one level in et voilà it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Moderator: The question can be closed as "caused by a typo" (not really a typo but then overall situation is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jonsharpe has mentioned in the comments the issue was not a YAML syntax error (as the error message indicated) but a semantic error of the specifics for GitHub actions: The `steps` block was not indented far enough.

Here's the corrected version:

```
on: [push, pull_request]

env:
  buildDir: ${{ github.workspace }}/build/

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, windows-2019, macos-10.15]
        include:
          - os: ubuntu-18.04
            triplet: x64-linux
          - os: ubuntu-20.04
            triplet: x64-linux
          - os: windows-2019
            triplet: x64-windows
          - os: macos-10.15
            triplet: x64-osx

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```